# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c++, dll, registration

An unhandled exception of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {613997F9-F489-4051-ACCB-1C7AE9C9E9A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I encounter this error on Visual Studio 2013 Community.

I have some native C++ code and I have compiled them as x64 Debug dlls.

Then on the top of those dlls, I used ATL to build COM project to expose some functionalities with interface.  (COM is only build as x64 Debug dll version).  In post_build event I add `"%WinDir%\system32\regsvr32 /s /c "$(TargetPath)"` to register my COM.  I'm pretty sure all linker and other options are set fine in project settings.  This COM dll is also built fine.  After compilation I can see the new typelib has been registered.

But when I add a VB.net or C# winform application to test the COM (Winform just supplies some input and call method in COM), I encounter this error.

I know this problem has been discussed many times but it seems all discussions are not my solution.  The old discussions are most like related to 32-bit, 64-bit confusion and other problems.

I can see from the registry following key name:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{613997F9-F489-4051-ACCB-1C7AE9C9E9A6}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{613997F9-F489-4051-ACCB-1C7AE9C9E9A6}\InprocServer32
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{613997F9-F489-4051-ACCB-1C7AE9C9E9A6}\Programmable
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{613997F9-F489-4051-ACCB-1C7AE9C9E9A6}\TypeLib
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{613997F9-F489-4051-ACCB-1C7AE9C9E9A6}\Version
```

I also can see the InProcServer32 key shows the right path to my COM dll.

My computer is 64-bit machine and OS is Windows 8.1

Anyone has some idea?

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to troubleshoot.  Standard reason is that you forgot to remove the jitter forcing so the .NET program runs in 32-bit mode.

Comment: I re-build a 32-bit version it works fine.   I